# angular filter on repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want to display a list of items that have a given property.
The property is fixed

```
var things = [{id:1, color: 'red'},{id:2, color: 'blue'},{id:3, color: 'red'},]

<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: {color: 'red'}">
    {{thing.id}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: {color: 'blue'}">
    {{thing.id}}
</div>
```

I am expecting this:

> 1 3
>
> 2

what I get is this:

> 1 2 3
>
> 1 2 3

The red and blue filter params are **baked-in**. I do not need them to be variable by user- or system-input.

I can't seem to find any documentation on ng-repeat filter that includes a simple **hard-coded** filter value.

Can I not do this in the vm alone? I do not want to have to make a call to the controller.

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you have should work. I tried to reproduce the problem but I get the result you said your expecting.

controller:

```
$scope.things = [{id:1, color: 'red'},{id:2, color: 'blue'},{id:3, color: 'red'}];
```

html:

```
first:<br/>
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: {color: 'red'}">
    {{thing.id}}
</div>
second:<br/>
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: {color: 'blue'}">
    {{thing.id}}
</div>
```

output:

```
first:
1
3
second:
2
```

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tHy5WG1oTkuaU4nNecq6?p=preview)

Comment: This answer works fine. @DaveC426913 please let us know your exact problem and which version of angular you are using? We can check in the same version.

Comment: Hm. OK, you've confirmed my expectation. The problem is surely elsewhere then. Thanks.